# Does TypeSafe Slick work on Scala 2.9.3?

Tags: scala, slick

Does TypeSafe Slick work on Scala 2.9.3? I get

```
[ERROR] exception when typing query.list
exception when typing query.listscala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$TypeError: class file needed by StatementInvoker is missing.
[INFO] class file needed by StatementInvoker is missing.
[INFO] reference type Either of object package refers to nonexisting symbol.
```

which goes away when I use Scala 2.10.x, but I'm too new to Scala to understand why.

```
import slick.session.Database
import scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery
import Database.threadLocalSession
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object PostgresDao {

  protected val conf = ConfigFactory.load

  def findFoo(a: Int, b: String): Option[Int] = {

    Database.forURL("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/bar", driver = "org.postgresql.Driver") withSession {

      val query = StaticQuery.query[(Int, String), Int](
        """
        select some_int
        from some_table t
        where t.a = ? and t.b = ?
        """.stripMargin)

      val list: List[Int] = query.list((a, b))

      if (list.isEmpty) {
        None
      }
      else {
        Some(list.head)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I shamelessly copy-past official doc here:

> [Slick requires Scala
>   2.10.](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/introduction.html#composable) (For Scala 2.9 please use [ScalaQuery](http://scalaquery.org/), the
>   predecessor of Slick).

Comment: I shamefully missed that. Thanks.